# Requests - Cannot download xls file from a link, stuck in loop or timeout?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to download a file from the following link:

```
url = "https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/content/fo/qtyfreeze.xls"
```

I have tried setting the `timeout`, `stream`, `headers`, `allow-redirects`. When I don't set the timeout, the response never completes. When I set the `timeout` I always get timeout error. I am able to download the file without issue in firefox and chrome.

The code I am using:

```
import requests as req

headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}

url = "https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/content/fo/qtyfreeze.xls"

# and variations of the following
resp = req.get(url, timeout=30, headers=headers)

# tried urllib
#urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,"/home/data/freeze_quantity.xls")
```

Comment: What is the file size?

Comment: Your code works for me. Maybe you need to close the request `with req.get(url, timeout=30, headers=headers) as resp:...`

Comment: Your code works. The problem can be elsewhere.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM file size is: 39,936 bytes

Answer (score 0):

Things changed (Can not pinpint the error, so, tried it my way):

1. Timeout Value: Increased from 30 seconds to 60 seconds.
2. Streaming: Added stream=True to handle streaming of large files.
3. File Writing in Chunks: Utilized iter_content to write response content in chunks.
4. Error Handling: Enhanced error handling with response.raise_for_status() and a try-except block.

Try this:

```
import requests
from retry import retry

headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}

url = "https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/content/fo/qtyfreeze.xls"

@retry(tries=3, delay=5)  # Retry 3 times with a 5-second delay between retries

#proxies = {
#    'http': 'http://your_proxy_here',
#    'https': 'http://your_proxy_here',
#}
#
#resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True, timeout=60, proxies=proxies)

def download_file():
    try:
        with requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True, timeout=60) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            with open('freeze_quantity.xls', 'wb') as file:
                for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
                    file.write(chunk)
        print("File downloaded successfully.")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error downloading file: {e}")

download_file()
```

Endnotes: I do not use proxy/proxy settings, so I can not verify if the code works its part or not.

Comment: Error downloading file: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nsearchives.nseindia.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=60). Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you able to download the file while being on the same network, through any browser?

Comment: Yes, it works if I use `selenium`, chrome, firefox.

Comment: This is strange, I had problem in your code, but not in the one I posted. But, check out the edited one, it uses not so changed code, and utilises retry, if all else does not work/ if you use a proxy, un-comment the parts and fill the respective fields.